# How to show abstract syntax tree of a grammar in bison?

Tags: bison, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing a grammar for a simple Pascal compiler in bison and I would like to visualize the parse tree for my grammar which I specified in pascal.y. Is it possible to graphically show the syntax tree based on my pascal.y file?

Answer (score 3):

Bison's `--graph` option produces a source file that you can render with `dot` from `graphviz`.

Answer (score 1):

Base on [BRPocock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8566598/4100915)'s answer in details.

1. Generate .dot file by `bison pascal.y --graph`. Now you will get pascal.dot
2. Make sure you have installed `graphviz`. [Download page](https://graphviz.org/download/)
3. Generate png picture file by `dot pascal.dot -T png -o pascal.png`
4. Now you will get pascal.png for a graphical rendering of the parser

Comment: Notwithstanding the upvotes for the answer you cite, which was never accepted, I don't think it actually answers the question, which requests a graphical representation of a syntax tree (for a parsed input), not of the parse automaton. Some parser generators can provide this (see, for example, the Antlr test harness) but it's not implemented by Bison.

Comment: I use the Windows Version of the DOT-Tool in 64-Bit Mode from the listed Download Page/Link above. In my Environment (I use **MinGW** - in both 32-Bit, and 64-Bit Mode) I get with the necessary Tool's an other File, so the command  `dot pascal.dot -T png -o pascal.png`  ends up with `pascal.gv` instead `pascal.dot` File.  This is just a Note to the Answer above (in helping for "searching" confusion - why the File pascal.dot can not be found). Thanks for reading.